# C# Xna achieve a desent scale effect with sprite fonts

Tags: c#, xna, scale

So I am working on a menu for my game. Here's the code for a single button:

```
// button class
public class ButtonGUI
{
    public SpriteFont spriteFont;
    string btnTxt;
    public Rectangle btnRect;
    Color colour;

    public ButtonGUI(string newTxt, Rectangle newRect, SpriteFont newSpriteFont, Color newColour)
    {
        spriteFont = newSpriteFont;
        btnRect = newRect;
        btnTxt = newTxt;
        colour = newColour;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        // TextOutliner() is a static helper class for drawing bordered spritefonts I made
        TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, spriteFont, btnTxt, btnRect.X, btnRect.Y, colour);
    }
}

// TitleScreen.cs
ButtonGUI btnPlay, btnPlay_2;
bool indexPlay;
string[] menuTxt;
SpriteFont GameFontLarge, GameFontLargeHover;

// LoadContent() method:
// Load both spritefonts....

menuTxt = new string[4];
menuTxt[0] = "Play Game";
menuTxt[1] = "Achievements";
menuTxt[2] = "Settings";
menuTxt[3] = "Exit Game";

btnPlay = new ButtonGUI(menuTxt[0], new Rectangle(150, 300, (int)GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[0]).X, (int)GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[0]).Y), GameFontLarge, Color.White);
btnPlay_2 = new ButtonGUI(menuTxt[0], new Rectangle(150, 300, (int)GameFontLargeHover.MeasureString(menuTxt[0]).X, (int)GameFontLargeHover.MeasureString(menuTxt[0]).Y), GameFontLargeHover, Color.Yellow);

// Update() method:
MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y, 1, 1);

if (mouseRect.Intersects(btnPlay.btnRect))
{
    indexPlay = true;
    if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) Game1.CurrentGameState = Game1.GameState.playScreen;
}
else indexPlay = false;

// Draw() method:
if (indexPlay)
{
    btnPlay_2.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
else btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

So I do all of this for 4 different buttons. The 2 sprite fonts are of the same font but with **different size**. Now when I test the game, when I mouse-hover on each of the buttons, the text changes from white to yellow and becomes larger. But since the button coordinates are done with `x = left-most; y = top-most` when the font changes the bigger font is drawn at the same position as the smaller one was. I want to get a decent "scale" effect when mouse-hovering. I mean I know I set the button position to that when initializing, but still I need some type of algorithm to find a way and draw the bigger font on the center of the older... What would be your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the position of your hover button based on the size difference:

```
var sizeDifference = btnPlay_2.btnRect.Size - btnPlay.btnRect.Size;
btnPlay_2.btnRect.Offset(-sizeDifference.X/2, -sizeDifference.Y/2);
```

Comment: I can't accept this answer if it's wrong... Replacing `Width` and `Height` with `X` and `Y` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Murray is probably not used to xna, so he just thought of Point from the System Drawing namespace. Vector2 is the xna equivalent to the Point struct